# How to call cURL post method in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, curl

I am working on an application which has multi-language translation. I decided to use `angular translate loader url`.

My cURL Request:

```
curl -X POST https://lokali.se/api/string/list \
 -d "api_token=641bc8455768b09589806c7d489640789cfb49e1" \
 -d "id=7509115157679787966292.60209031"
```

How can I use this cURL request in my Angular script?

My angular Script is something like this

```
var myApp = angular.module('translateExample', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

myApp.config(function($translateProvider) {
$translateProvider.useUrlLoader('my_cURL_Request_here');
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
});

myApp.controller('landingCtrl', function($translate, $scope) {
$scope.language = 'en';  
$scope.languages = ['en', 'fr', 'da'];
$scope.changeLanguage = function () {
  $translate.use($scope.language);
};
});
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

```
myApp.controller('landingCtrl', function($translate, $scope, $http) {
    $http({
        url: 'https://lokali.se/api/string/list',
        method: "POST",
        data: { 
          'api_token' : '641bc8455768b09589806c7d489640789cfb49e1', 
          'id': '7509115157679787966292.60209031'
        }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
            // success
    }, 
    function(response) { // optional
            // failed
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain bit brief as we can't able to inject $http into config() directly

Comment: You have to use it in the controller, not in the config.

Comment: I don't know what angular translate loader url is but you asked how to make a curl request and that is a way to do that.